# Static dataflow graph generator for Python?

Tags: python, programming-languages, static-analysis, dataflow, graphml

I've been struggling for quite some time to find a static dataflow graph generator for Python.

This is my ideal: 
Given a small python script `example.py`, (written in Python3), return some representation of the data flow graph.

I was able to achieve this result using IBM's pyflowgraph, https://github.com/IBM/pyflowgraph which outputs data in `graph.ml` format, unfortunately this package only performs dynamic analysis.

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a DFG tool that could do this type of static dataflow analysis for Python?

Comment: also, https://serge-sans-paille.github.io/pythran-stories/gast-beniget-use-def-chains-for-python-programs.html.

Answer (score -1):

I just found this open source project focused on dataflow analysis for Python. Check it out!
https://github.com/SMAT-Lab/Scalpel/

It's made in Python too; haven't used it, but looks very interesting!

This is the pre-print of their paper:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/2202.11840.pdf

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31452034)